# Почему ЕГО произносится как ЕВО?

Tags: фонетика

Как объяснить иностранцу, что в слове *его* буква Г читается как В? Есть ли какое-то правило?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да. В словах "его", "сегодня" (="сего дня") и в окончаниях прилагательных, причастий и местоимений в родительном падеже (типа *моего, никакого, красного, записанного*) закреплено историческое произношение. Это один из немногих случаев, когда русская орфография отступает от фонетического принципа в пользу традиции. Произношение [ево],[краснава] и т. п. - появилось не ранее XVII  века в московском говоре, позднее принятом за основу общелитературной нормы.

Если иностранцу все это непонятно или неинтересно, можно сказать просто, что это - дань традиции, которая есть, наверное, в любом языке.

Comment: «Русская орфография отступает» ======= Просто стоит на своём, отстаивая «свои» традиции в письменности и отчасти — дикции, как здесь иногда говорят, мёртвого, церковно-славянского языка.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы не утруждаете себя дочитать фразу до конца. А у орфографии есть принципы, основной из которых - морфологический, следующий - фонетический. Вот от него орфография и отступает. А "на своем" стоял только Штирлиц.

Comment: Вам точно кажется. Цель была не возразить, а дополнить.